# Line connecting data points reappears when using Tikzplotlib

Tags: python, latex, tikz

I am running into a problem when using matplotlib.pyplot.errorbars when I try to export the graph to tex afterwards using tikzplotlib.

In python I switch off the line connecting the datapoints using `ls='None'` and it plots correctly the regular `show()` function. However, when I save the graph via tikzplotlib to a .tex file and then load it into my latex document this line reappears. I have tried the other two values that should switch of these lines (`ls='none'` and `ls=''`) and they give the same problem. I have also tried setting the linewidth to 0, but that makes the error bars and markers disappear as well. Any idea for how to permanently switch off the datapoint connecting line? I want to add a fitted line, so the other line is really annoying.

Example python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tikzplotlib
from scipy import stats


temperatures = [20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0]
length = np.array([4.9,6,7.2,8,9.1,10, 11, 12.4])

# Fit linear function
xnew = np.linspace(np.amin(temperatures), np.amax(temperatures), num=41, endpoint=True)
fitted_line = stats.linregress(temperatures, length)

#Plot data
plt.errorbar(temperatures, length, markersize=2, yerr=0.25, ls='None') 
plt.plot(xnew, fitted_line.intercept + fitted_line.slope*xnew, '-')
    
# Add labels and title
plt.xlabel("Temperature (°C)")
plt.ylabel("Length increase (mm)")
 
# plt.show()
tikzplotlib.save("Test.tex", encoding='utf-8')
```

This give the following graph:

[image: Plot created in python]

I then import this into my latex file using

```
\begin{figure}
    \input{Test.tex}
\end{figure}
```

which gives this graph:

[image: graph using latex]

The orange line is the fitted line, which is wanted. The blue line is not.

The tex file Test.tex looks as follows:

```
% This file was created by tikzplotlib v0.9.8.
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.12156862745098,0.466666666666667,0.705882352941177}
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{1,0.498039215686275,0.0549019607843137}

\begin{axis}[
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
x grid style={white!69.0196078431373!black},
xlabel={Temperature (°C)},
xmin=19.65, xmax=27.35,
xtick style={color=black},
y grid style={white!69.0196078431373!black},
ylabel={Length increase (mm)},
ymin=4.25, ymax=13.05,
ytick style={color=black}
]
\path [draw=color0, semithick]
(axis cs:20,4.65)
--(axis cs:20,5.15);

\path [draw=color0, semithick]
(axis cs:21,5.75)
--(axis cs:21,6.25);

\path [draw=color0, semithick]
(axis cs:22,6.95)
--(axis cs:22,7.45);

\path [draw=color0, semithick]
(axis cs:23,7.75)
--(axis cs:23,8.25);

\path [draw=color0, semithick]
(axis cs:24,8.85)
--(axis cs:24,9.35);

\path [draw=color0, semithick]
(axis cs:25,9.75)
--(axis cs:25,10.25);

\path [draw=color0, semithick]
(axis cs:26,10.75)
--(axis cs:26,11.25);

\path [draw=color0, semithick]
(axis cs:27,12.15)
--(axis cs:27,12.65);

\addplot [semithick, color1]
table {%
20 4.95
20.175 5.13125
20.35 5.3125
20.525 5.49375
20.7 5.675
20.875 5.85625
21.05 6.0375
21.225 6.21875
21.4 6.4
21.575 6.58125
21.75 6.7625
21.925 6.94375
22.1 7.125
22.275 7.30625
22.45 7.4875
22.625 7.66875
22.8 7.85
22.975 8.03125
23.15 8.2125
23.325 8.39375
23.5 8.575
23.675 8.75625
23.85 8.9375
24.025 9.11875
24.2 9.3
24.375 9.48125
24.55 9.6625
24.725 9.84375
24.9 10.025
25.075 10.20625
25.25 10.3875
25.425 10.56875
25.6 10.75
25.775 10.93125
25.95 11.1125
26.125 11.29375
26.3 11.475
26.475 11.65625
26.65 11.8375
26.825 12.01875
27 12.2
};
\addplot [semithick, color0]
table {%
20 4.9
21 6
22 7.2
23 8
24 9.1
25 10
26 11
27 12.4
};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Can you show the `Test.tex` file so we can what's going on there?

Comment: Just added the tex file

Comment: In case you don't frequently recreate `Test.tex`, you would around the problem by deleting the last `\addplot [semithick, color0] table {...};`

Comment: Looks like that is the way to go. I'll just add a warning in my document to check for this. Thanks for your help!